# Tail field of random variables in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ i. i. d. with values in $\mathbb{Z}$, define $S_0 := 0$, $S_n := X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ and $R_n := \{S_n = 0\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Show that $\mathbf{P}[\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} R_n ] \in \{0, 1\}\, .$

Can somebody give me some hints for this exercise? It has something to do with exchangeability, though I don't see how. It seems intuitive that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} R_n$ is in the tail field, but how to prove that rigorously?

Comment: You want to compute the probability that $S_n=0$ infinitely often. Suppose $p$ is the probability that the sum ever gets back to 0, given it starts at 0.  Consider what happens if $p<1$.

Comment: @Michael Indeed, zero-one laws only complicate things here.

Comment: @Michael: I agree, that it seems more like a question about Markov chains, but in this case it must have something to do with exchangeability.

Comment: I don't see any need for exchangeability. Have you considered how many times we get back to zero, as in my first comment?

Comment: @Michael: It's an exercise in a chapter about exchangeability. How could that be used?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this is a direct application of the Hewitt–Savage zero–one law.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%2DSavage%5Fzero%2Done%5Flaw

The Kolmogorov zero-one law is not directly applicable here.

Comment: The problem is that the events $R_m$ are not independent, so describing the tail in terms of those does not allow use of the Kolmogorov law. To me, this seems more like a "Markov chain" question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the events are independent in $F_{\infty}$. Whether the sum is 0 only depends on the final value $X_n$ and not on $R_{n-1}$.

Comment: No.  Suppose the $X_i$ variables are iid in $\{-1,1\}$.  Then if $S_{n-1}=0$, we know $S_n$ cannot be 0, it will be either 1 or -1.

Comment: Fixed it. @Michael. You were right.

Comment: Looks like your edit to the use of Hewitt-Savage zero-one law is what Qyburn is asking about (in terms of exchangeability), even though this question can be answered more easily from basic probability concepts (i.e, you only need to know what a geometric random variable is). For example, it is pretty easy to compute the probability we return to 0 exactly 12 times via the language in my very first comment.